# How to access database cell from jquery using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am building website where users have their profile page and can edit biography

When they edit biography i need to do it without refreshing whole page. At first i did not use MySQl for storing data and did it all in text files as i am very familiar with C programming language. With text files everything run smoothly, i just save url of my text file in one variable and when i recieve succes from server i just use jquery load() function to load changed text from text file.

The thing is i dont know how to do that with databases. Is there any way to make something like url of the table cell ?

Comment: Just change the server program to read and write the biography to a database row instead of the file. The basic structure is the same.

Comment: Avoid using text files, sometimes they can be accessed without proper permission. Create a MySQL table with at least two rows, `USER ID` and `BIO`. When you load the users profile get the users ID and make the query. `SELECT bio FROM myTable WHERE user_id = 1`. Although I recommend you merge this with a users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know how to make AJAX calls and know some programming this will be effortless.

Using a database is a good and efficient move which you did well.

Migrating to a relational database such as MySQL should be painless. All you need to do is create a table called Users(which contains their attributes like name, address,biography etc).

Then you can make queries like SELECT 'attribute' from users WHERE user_id = 'userid' ;

I suggest you take a short time to learn SQL [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp?PHPSESSID=300ae3404d5fa2612f238abeebb8869c)  then from there you can follow up some tutorials on how to create MySQL connections [php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)